Why does path alias doesn't work in remix vite?
I made an alias at tsconfig.json like this.
But Remix doesn't recognize this alias.
My project has a structure like this.
root
  └app
    └routes
      └\_index.tsx
      └components
        └success.tsx

tsconfig.json
{
  "include": [
    "remix.env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "**/.server/**/*.ts",
    "**/.server/**/*.tsx",
    "**/.client/**/*.ts",
    "**/.client/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ES2022"],
    "types": ["@remix-run/node", "vite/client"],
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "strict": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./app/*"]
    },

    // Vite takes care of building everything, not tsc.
    "noEmit": true
  }
}

vite.config.js
import { vitePlugin as remix } from "@remix-run/dev";
import { installGlobals } from "@remix-run/node";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";

installGlobals();

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [remix(), tsconfigPaths()],
});

_index.tsx
import type { MetaFunction } from "@remix-run/node";
import Success from "~/routes/components/success";

I already visited remix github but cannot solve this issue.
IDE recognize this alias and automatically import my module (success).
But, remix doesn't recognize this and make error on page.
Does anyone has issue like this? And give me solution, please.
You can also see whole project on https://github.com/melodist/MolluFrontend

What if you used an absolute path, i.e. something like "~/routes/*": ["/src/root/app/routes/*"]? Usage import Success from "~routes/components/success";.

Your import in _index.tsx is import Success from "@app/routes/components/success"; which uses a different path shortcut not defined. Use import Success from "~/routes/components/success";.

@DrewReese Thanks for your answer. But I got a same error when I defined ~/* alias. I used many differenet aliases such as @app, and uploaded files are history for this trial

The import in _index.tsx is using @app/routes/components/... You did not define an @app alias.
Changing it to ~/routes/components/... works since that's the default alias to the app folder.

NOTE: I would not recommend adding components folder inside routes. Remix is treating this as a a route. If you still want that, then you should add components to the remix ignoredRouteFiles config.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ran21q?file=app%2Froutes%2F_index.tsx

Thanks for your answer. But I got a same error when I defined ~/* alias. I used many differenet aliases such as @app, and uploaded files is a history for this trial.

I solved this problem indirectly.
I found an example project for remix using tailwindcss (https://github.com/remix-run/examples/tree/main/tailwindcss) and copied them into my project, and it works.
When comparing the files (vite.config.ts, tsconfig.json) of both projects, files in both projects are identical. So, it seems to be a dependency problem for such libraries.
